# What is the intuition behind the definition of a Markov Chain being $\pi$-invariant?

Tags: probability-theory, statistics, stochastic-processes

In Markov Chain literature, one definition is that a chain admits $\pi$ as an **invariant distribution** if:

$$
\forall \ \theta^t \in \mathcal{H} \ \ \int_{\mathcal{H}}\pi(\theta^{t-1})K(\theta^t|\theta^{t-1})d\theta^{t-1} = \pi(\theta^t)
$$

where $\theta^1, \theta_2, \ldots$ are sequences of a Markov Chain and $K(\theta^t|\theta^{t-1})$ is a transition or Markov Kernel. In this case, we say that the chain is **$\pi$-invariant.**

I am wondering if anyone has any intuition here as to why this is the case. My understanding from Stochastic Processes is that if $\lambda P = \lambda$, then $\lambda$ is an invariant distribution for $P$ a transition matrix. However, the above definition confuses me. Does anyone have any ideas how to interpret it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you write out $\lambda P = \lambda$ you get
$$\sum_i P_{ij} \lambda_i = \lambda_j$$
or in another way,
$$\sum_{x_{t-1}} p(x_t \mid x_{t-1}) \lambda(x_{t-1}) = \lambda(x_t)$$
where $\lambda$ is the stationary distribution.

If you replace the sum with an integral and do some more pattern matching, you can see that $\lambda P = \lambda$ is a special case of the integral in your question.

Comment: Got it! So the above representation you have is for a discrete space and the integral is introduced in the continuous case?

Comment: @user321627 Yes, essentially